# Push notifications sometimes call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions instead of didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an app running on iOS 13 that receives push notifications that contain both an alert message and content-available (to allow background download of content). But I noticed an issue where some background downloads are never allowed to start.

Looking in my logs, I can see that most of the time `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` is called as intended and the downloads are started.

But sometimes (even during midnight when the phone is not in use) it instead chooses to call `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` with the push payload. In this case `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called at all.

Here are my questions:

1. Is this the intended behavior? The documentation is kind of vague but it sounds like didReceiveRemoteNotification should be called in every case.
2. I don't mind starting the download in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if that's what it takes, but this method is also called when a user just taps on push. Can I see the difference between those two cases?

I have the "Remote notifications" Background Mode enabled, and a push payload typically looks like this:

```
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "loc-args": [
            "Name",
            "Description"
        ],
        "loc-key": "new_release_body",
        "title-loc-args": {
        },
        "title-loc-key": "new_release_title"
    },
    "category": "NEW_RELEASE",
    "content-available": 1,
    "mutable-content": 1
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Since writing this answer, it appears as if this behavior has changed in iOS 14. Instead of calling *either* function, it will now call *both*, **if** the app is launched with a push notification. Since we can't be sure this won't change again in the future, we're still handling pushes in both places, but we've had to make sure that the push will only be acted upon once.

---

In the end I decided to handle push notifications in both `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`.

If the application is launched with a remote notification (and the `applicationState` is `.background` - meaning it will not be triggered by tapping a push notification) I attempt to start a download the same way I normally would when a push notification is received via `applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Below is some pseudo code which I'll run in production and see how it performs. The results while testing are excellent.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any], application.applicationState == .background {
        handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: remoteNotification)
    }
    
    return true
}

public func applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification(with userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: userInfo, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

private func handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)? = nil) {
    // A shared function that handles push notification and starts a download
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user killed the app manually, apple won't wake your app in the background until the user will launch the app again, or will restart his device.

Maybe the cases you received those in the `didFinishLaunching` is if you killed your app, so when you will open the app again you will received it there? Or maybe you killed the app but then restarted the device?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application#discussion

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would have been my guess but `didFinishLaunching` can even be called in the middle of the night when I'm fast asleep.

Answer (score 0):

if your app in foreground mood  it will call didFinishWithOptions. you should call

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    let payload = NotificationPayload(notification_type:notification_type)
    self.handleWillPresentNotifications(payload: payload)
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

after this you need to write below lines in didFinish

```
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (_, error) in
        guard error == nil else{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

// This is new Delegate that you need to implement also in to your appDelegate file.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { print("Recived: \(userInfo)") completionHandler(.NewData) }
```

Comment: In the foreground I have no issues. The issue is that when my app has been killed by the system and needs to relaunch, it only calls `didFinishLaunching` instead of `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

Comment: It will call did finish definitely. And didrecieve notification also did you confirm permissions

Comment: I added one more function call that one hope this will work as you expected